# How to allow user to run only specific binaries

Tags: linux, security, access-control-list, selinux, user-permissions

I'm adding user `logviewer` with `/sbin/nologin/` and to my system.
My custom service is running eg. `sudo -u logviewer less --follow-name /var/log/messages`.

But still there are ways to run other command as that user. I would like to only allow user `logviewer` to run specific binaries, like `less` `tail` `cat`.

Is it possible? I'm not too familiar with selinux to use it in that case.
Is there a guide to `restric all` and `allow specific` binaries for a user?

Answer (score 2):

GNU less is a fancy pager. Set env var `LESSSECURE=1` to disable some features like running ! shell commands. See `man less`, security section.

Restricting a execution of programs based on rules, and blocking other things, is called an allowlist. A subset of [execution prevention](https://attack.mitre.org/mitigations/M1038/) mitigations.

An application might be confined to a chroot or container with only the minimum set of software defined. However, this likely is not a good fit for your example of a log parsing program where it is not the only thing happening on the host.

A libre implementation of application blocking would be [fapolicyd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening). Red Hat has taken it up, for example. In this case, you might have:

```
allow perm=execute uid=logviewer : path=/usr/bin/less 
allow perm=execute uid=logviewer : path=/usr/bin/tail
allow perm=execute uid=logviewer : path=/usr/bin/cat 
allow perm=execute uid=logviewer : path=/sbin/nologin
deny_audit perm=execute uid=logviewer : all
```

Or, selinux exists as a different method for access control, which allows for custom policy.

Although a strict execution policy around this user may only matter to you if it is plausible they can run other commands. With less secured, no credentials for the service account, and the allowed commands in switch user policy (sudo, polkit, doas) it is no longer trivial to run arbitrary commands.

---

There are ways to avoid needing a log viewer on the host. Consider centralized logging, with some application to parse and show log events.

Answer (score -1):

As starting point the sudoers file would as well allow limiting to specific command.

https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers

````
ray     rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, PASSWD: /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm```
````

Comment: question was about unprivileged binaries, as you can see `sudo` was used to change running user not to elevate permissions